# Compare 2 list and print out each identical data in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am comparing 2 list. Each containing formatted phone number. I want to upload the phone number to firestore or print out if they match. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
  formattedPhonesLocal.forEach((element1) {
    formattedPhonesOnline.forEach((element2) {
      if (element1 == element2) {
        print("this is element 2 $element2");
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: What problem do you have? Also, what is the type of `formattedPhonesLocal` and `formattedPhonesOnline`? And the type of `element1` and `element2`.

Comment: formattedPhonesLocal and formattedPhonesOnline are both list. I want to compare them and check for identical data in them while printing out those identical data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not performing a separate comparison for each item in the nested loop, so are going to get a lot of false positives.

If you want to use a nested loop, memoize the results like this:

```
formattedPhonesLocal.forEach((element1) {
  var isFound = false
  formattedPhonesOnline.forEach((element2) {
    if (element1 == element2) {
      isFound = true;
    }
  });
  print(isFound);
});
```

Or you can use the [`contains` method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/contains.html) that is built into the array/list instead of the nested loop:

```
formattedPhonesLocal.forEach((element1) {
  var isFound = formattedPhonesOnline.contains(element1);
  print(isFound);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first one worked though  I had to do a little modification

Comment: It says I need 15 reputation to upvote and I cannot edit either. Edit queue is full

Comment: You can always accept answers on questions you ask by checking the box ✔ next to it.  --- I'm not sure what it means that the edit queue is full though. Never saw that before, but hope it gets fixed for you.

Comment: I just clicked the checkbox. Thanks

Comment: @Frank see [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345125). It's actually a really common issue here on SO for <2k users :(

Comment: Thanks @user17242583 I didn't know of that limit. There's probably a good reason for it, I just wish it didn't affect us here. :)